# Java EBean Play Framework. findOne() not working ? how to return one object instead of findList()?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, ebean

//Below code is Not Working
//Here, my query just returns one object, So I am trying to use findOne() //method.

```
Query<Topic> query = Ebean.find(Topic.class);
Topic topic = new Topic();
Topic topic=Topic.find.where().eq("columnName", "nameToMatch").findOne();
```

//Below part is working if I use findList(). But I have to do get(0) to //fetch the topic which is not good practice I think.

```
List<Topic> topicList = Ebean.find(Topic.class).where().eq("columnName", "NametoMatch").findList();
topicList.get(0)
```

Can anyone provide ideas how to return just One Object instead of list ?

Comment: did you mean `Topic topicList = Ebean.find(Topic.class).where().eq("columnName", "NametoMatch").findOne();`

Comment: yes @YCF_L if I do this Topic topicList = Ebean.find(Topic.class).where().eq("columnName", "NametoMatch").findOne(); I am not getting Symbol Not Found error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `findOne` exists in Ebean, but when I need to retrieve only one object I use `findUnique()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the object you want to find is unique, you can get it via `findUnique()`: `Topic.find.where().eq("columnName", "nameToMatch").findUnique();`

Otherwise you can use `findList()` with `setMaxRows()`, because you don't want to load in memory whole result set:
`Topic.find.where().eq("columnName", "nameToMatch").setMaxRows(1).findList();`